# Record and capture NTFS activity

Tags: windows, profiling, ntfs

Good day.
Say, please, is there any chance to intercept and record NTFS activity? 
Procmon records system actions on NTFS (create, open, delete, etc.), but does not show the body of blocks that placed on files while saving them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a file system filter driver. Here's a very good tutorial on it:

[File System Filter Driver Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial)

Comment: This article is a *very* brief introduction about Legacy File System Filter drivers, which are deprecated. The supported method for writing a file system filter is now through the Mini-filter Model. See the MSDN docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy task to write kernel mode code!

Befor you start this adventure, you could have a closer look at [Sysinternal Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb842062), written by Mark Russinovich. Maybe you find something usefull there and if not, then the tools may help you writing the minifilter!